# Why there is 404 error in Stripe CLI using Next JS 14

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am trying to integrate Stripe with my Next JS project. I have set up Stripe CLI to test locally. I have a payment link and upon clicking on it and completing the payment, some data I am printing from the Stripe line items. The payment is getting completed but in the terminal I am seeing 404 for the POST request response. I am not sure why I am getting it wrong. I have verified all my secret keys and those are correct and are stored in the .env.local file.

**Code:**
**Location:** /app/api/webhook.tsx

```
import Stripe from "stripe";
import getRawBody from "raw-body";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'] as string, {
    apiVersion: '2023-10-16'
});

const webhooksecret = process.env['STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET'] as string

// add this line else there will be stream not readable error
export const dynamicParams = false;

export default async function StripeHandler(request: NextApiRequest, response: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
        // if not POST req -> return 405
        if(request.method !== 'POST') {
            return response.status(405).send('Only POST request allowed.');
        }

        const signature: any = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
        const rawBody = await getRawBody(request);

        let event;

        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, signature, webhooksecret);
        } catch (error: any) {
            return response.status(400).send(`Bad Request: ${error.message}`);
        }
        
        if(event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
            const sessionLineItems = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
                (event.data.object as any).id,
                {
                    expand: ['line_items']
                }
            );

            const lineItems = sessionLineItems.line_items as any;

            if(!lineItems) {
                response.status(500).send("Internal Server Error.");
            }

            try {
                console.log(lineItems.data);
            } catch (error: any) {
                response.status(500).send("Order Not Saved.");
            }
        }
        response.status(200).end();
    } catch (error: any) {
        return 
    }
}
```

**Stripe webhook** command:

```
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/webhook
```

**CMD response** after completing the payment successfully:

```
2024-01-27 13:00:07   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3Od6L2SEPGwsgWeg1WWA5BWe]
2024-01-27 13:00:07   --> payment_intent.requires_action [evt_3Od6L2SEPGwsgWeg1xhLgUx1]
2024-01-27 13:00:10  <--  [404] POST http://localhost:3000/api/webhook [evt_3Od6L2SEPGwsgWeg1xhLgUx1]
2024-01-27 13:00:10  <--  [404] POST http://localhost:3000/api/webhook [evt_3Od6L2SEPGwsgWeg1WWA5BWe]
2024-01-27 13:00:19   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3Od6L2SEPGwsgWeg1d8ATaWw]
2024-01-27 13:00:19  <--  [404] POST http://localhost:3000/api/webhook [evt_3Od6L2SEPGwsgWeg1d8ATaWw]
2024-01-27 13:00:20   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1Od6LGSEPGwsgWegXroSxK4g]
2024-01-27 13:00:20   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3Od6L2SEPGwsgWeg1EbPyunR]
2024-01-27 13:00:20  <--  [404] POST http://localhost:3000/api/webhook [evt_1Od6LGSEPGwsgWegXroSxK4g]
2024-01-27 13:00:20  <--  [404] POST http://localhost:3000/api/webhook [evt_3Od6L2SEPGwsgWeg1EbPyunR]
```

Answer (score 0):

### For Next.js v14, This code will surely help you.

File Path will be like
`/app/api/webhook/route.ts`

```
// route.ts

import Stripe from "stripe";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const webhooksecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET as string;

const stripe = new Stripe(webhooksecret, {
  apiVersion: "2023-10-16",
});


export async function POST(request) {
  const rawBody = await request.text();
  const signature = request.headers.get("stripe-signature");

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, signature, webhooksecret);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Webhook Error " + err.message },
      { status: 400 }
    );
  }

  if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
    const sessionLineItems = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
      (event.data.object as any).id,
      {
        expand: ["line_items"],
      }
    );

    const lineItems = sessionLineItems.line_items as any;

    if (!lineItems) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "Internal Server Error." },
        {
          status: 500,
        }
      );
    } else {
      try {
        console.log(lineItems.data);
      } catch (error: any) {
        return NextResponse.json(
            { message: "Order Not Saved" },
            {
              status: 500,
            }
          );
      }
    }


  }else {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Payment is not Successfully Paid" },
      {
        status: 400,
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Destructure Code**

1. export function POST(request){} directly listen to POST method in your route.tsx likewise export function GET(request){} will listen GET Request
2. request.body() will return Raw body
3. import {NextResponse} from "next/server"

***Hope this will help you.***

Comment: As using typescript so `export async function POST(request) {...}` will be `export async function POST(request: any) {...}`. Else, there would be type error.

Answer (score 0):

Disable [bodyParser](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/nextjs/pages/api/webhooks.ts#L52) and try again. You can also try out the example code for next.js from Stripe's example [repo](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/nextjs/pages/api/webhooks.ts#L52)

Comment: I had tried with that but bodyParser has been deprecated in Next JS 14.